# How to get TortoiseHG to perform a pre-diff action

Tags: mercurial, hook, tortoisehg, mercurial-hook

I have a pre-diff hook in my hg setup but it is not being executed when I try to commit my changes.

What I'm trying to do is generate the database schema file before commit so that it will appear in the list of changes.

I also have an update hook which works fine. Is TortoiseHG not performing an hg diff command? Which hook could I use instead?

Comment: Precommit is too late, I want to check in my changes including the database changes so that it is easy to find out what exactly change for 1 workitem (and it's more productive then having to do 2 commits right after each other)

Comment: pre-commit, in which you'll build schema and commit changed in **this** commit. See http://lildude.co.uk/mercurial-precommit-isnt-entirely-pre

Comment: I tried that, it's still too late: the sql script needs to be generated before an hg diff is performed else the new script doesn't show up in the list of changes.

Comment: This question is better suited to the TortoiseHg discussion list (https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/tortoisehg-discuss).  I would guess that TortoiseHg does not use `hg diff` in the way you expect.

Comment: THG have auto-commit list per-repo basis. Add sql to it

Comment: @LazyBadger The whole point is that I can inspect the list of items to commit before I do so, I never want auto-commits

Comment: @TimHenigan So, do you know how it uses it or what it uses instead? I asked here so that it will be beneficial for everybody, the mailinglists archive doesn't look like it's searchable.

Comment: @sebastiaan: I added an answer below to describe how thg diffs work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseHg (as of v2.1.4) performs diffs in at least 3 ways, none of which use a raw `hg diff` command:

1. In the "Revision Details" window of the Workbench, there is a file-level unified diff shown.  This diff is obtained through [`mdiff.unidiff`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/file/3eb1a90ea409/mercurial/mdiff.py#l91) method in `mdiff.py`.  This method bypasses the hook mechanism.
2. If a changeset (or range of changesets) is selected in the revision graph, the user can ask for a "Visual Diff".  This method copies the files from the selected revisions to a temporary directory and then compares them with an external visual diff tool.  This method also bypasses the hook mechanism.
3. In the "Manifest" view, you can select a file, right-click and "Compare file revisions".  This uses a custom visual diff utility which also bypasses the hook mechanism.

As far as I know, TortoiseHg does not expose any hooks for its diff mechanism.